# Do I need any transit visa in Geneva airport?

Tags: visas, transit, geneva, gva, syrian-citizens

I am travelling to Montreal from Beirut, Lebanon and transiting through Geneva, Switzerland. I am holding a Syrian passport. Do I need any transit visa in Geneva airport?